# Accessing a remote database -- best practices

Tags: c#, database

I want to create a C# .NET WPF application which communicates with my external Linux server. On my server runs a MySQL database.

What is the best way to access the database (select, DML) without accessing it directly via ADO.NET?

I have thought of a webservice, but I don't know how to create and access a webservice with C# on a linux server. Also I need a secure connection (https).

I hope you can tell me best practices.

Comment: What's wrong with ADO.NET?

Comment: Are you fixed on ADO.NET, there are several libraries such as NHibernate which can be configured to read from a range of DBs including MySQL

Comment: I don't want my application to access the database directly. If the host has bind 127.0.0.1 in the MySQL config, I can't access it.
I thought of a middleware-like solution or webservices.

Comment: What does this question have to do with WPF?

Comment: Sorry removed the tag it was recommended.

Comment: Accessing the database directly is probably best practice. Writing a WS is another option. If you want to write it in C#, you can use Mono, but there are of course a billion options when writing a WS, it's not like you have to write the linux WS in C# just to access it from C#.

Comment: Do you plan to use c# server side too (Mono) ?

Comment: One way is to write a API in any language and program your application against a API

Comment: No on my server I thought of Java (It's the only alternative besides PHP, HTML, ...). As you can see I have no experience in that. :/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A web service is a good way to decouple the client and server portions of your app, provide enhanced security for accessing the database, etc.

You're using MySQL on a Linux server, so if you wanted to use .NET for your server's web service as well, you'll need to use Mono http://www.mono-project.com/. Also, take a look at WCF, as this provides a lot of the web service functionality you'll need to build on. If I remember correctly, there's even a way to automatically generate an entire web service from your existing ADO.NET data layer.

If however you're comfortable using a different framework / language on the server side, there are plenty of options out there if you don't want to roll your own. Search for "restful mysql" and you'll get some leads, e.g.:

> [Exposing MySQL database/table using REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771485/exposing-mysql-database-table-using-rest)
>
> http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/
>
> http://restsql.org

Security is going to be very important here of course. HTTPS will encrypt your communications, but you'll also need to implement solid authentication.

Answer (score 1):

`Client application in C# <-> Server application in Java <-> MySQL database`

Do I get it right ? If so, maybe the easiest thing you can do, is a simple [servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) that takes a stored procedure name and parameters on the url, calls MySQL, and serializes result back at your client application (say, in XML).

Give the stored procedures allowed to be called that way a common prefix so you can easily filter out potentially malicious calls, or use MySQL security to do so.

Comment: Well I don't want to use Java anymore. I will look into PHP webservices as PHP runs on my server by default.